# How to direct a data-toggle modal to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a list of table for survey form and each one of them have a button/asp-action to view the answers of at least 3 competitors. but I need to select the competitors of a survey form using a modal. inside that modal, I should populate the body with a checkbox of competitors who answered that survey form. How can I push through to direct the data-toggle modal to the controller?

Here is my View:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SurveyNames.Count; i++)
      {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model.SurveyNames[i].SurveyName
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.SurveyNames[i].SurveyFor
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.SurveyNames[i].Description
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.SurveyNames[i].CreatedBy
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.SurveyNames[i].Status
            </td>

            <td>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <a asp-action="ViewCompetitors" asp-route-id="@Model.SurveyNames[i].Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChooseCompetitors">View Competitors</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

And this is my Controller, it should return the values to index modal:

```
public IActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var model = new CompetitorAnswerViewModel();
            var SurveyList = _context.MainSurvey.ToList();

             foreach (var zsurvey in SurveyList)
            {
                model.SurveyNames.Add(new survey { Id = zsurvey.Id, SurveyName = zsurvey.SurveyName, SurveyFor = zsurvey.SurveyFor,Description = zsurvey.Description,CreatedBy = zsurvey.CreatedBy,Status = zsurvey.Status}) ;
            }

            var competitorList = _context.SurveyCompetitor.ToList().Where(x => x.MainSurveyId == id);

             foreach (var competitors in competitorList)
            {
                model.CompetitorNames.Add(new Competitor { CompetitorName = competitors.CompetitorName});
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

I should populate the body with a checkbox of competitors who answered that survey form. But it doesn't forward to the controller whenever I click "View Competitors".

[image]

Comment: just a suggestion, won't solve the issue. the code could be a lot cleaner if you used a `foreach` instead of `for` in the first line.

Comment: Hi @NevilleNazerane, it shows an error whenever I use `foreach` statement. and I am using a 1 model of a 2 database tables.

Comment: `foreach (var sname in Model.SurveyNames)` when used with `@sname.SurveyName` etc must work fine

Comment: is your `_context` a dbcontext of ef core

Comment: Yes. It worked as you said :) Thank you! The error is because I did not put `Model.` in `Model.SurveyNames`. Lol.

Comment: if you are talking about a bootstrap modal it would be in your HTML/razor code. you wouldn't have to push anything to the controller to create it

Comment: I want the table data id to pass it to the contoller to filter the survey competitors and then return the filtered data to the modal in the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the table data id to pass it to the contoller to filter the survey competitors and then return the filtered data to the modal in the same index

You could put the `Competitors` view in a partial view and render it to `Index` view using ajax.

1.Create the partial view in `Shared` folder `/Views/Shared/_CompetitorsPartialView.cshtml`

```
@model YourViewModel
<div class="col-md-12">
Your View
</div>
```

2. Return the filtered data to this partail view

```
public IActionResult ViewCompetitors(int id)
    {
        // filter logic
        return PartialView("_CompetitorsPartialView",YourViewModel);
    }
```

3.Use ajax in `Index` view.

Modify `<a>` to `<button>`:

```
<button id = "ViewCompetitors" onclick="viewCompetitor(@item.CustomerId)">View Competitors</button>
```

Modal and ajax:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ChooseCompetitors" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="showresults"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function viewCompetitor(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: '/Home/ViewCompetitors/' + id,//your url
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ChooseCompetitors").modal();//open modal
                $('#showresults').html(result);//populate view to modal

            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```